React native viro showing blank screen
Hi am currently on R & D of an app for meta quest using react native.
Saw a package viro which is modified as @reactvision/react-viro which supports AR/VR, but using that leaves with a black blank screen.
Below is the code I tried.
`
import {
  ViroARScene,
  ViroARSceneNavigator,
  ViroScene,
  ViroText,
  ViroTrackingReason,
  ViroTrackingStateConstants,
  ViroVRSceneNavigator,
} from "@reactvision/react-viro";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const HelloWorldSceneAR = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Initializing AR...");

  function onInitialized(state: any, reason: ViroTrackingReason) {
    console.log("onInitialized", state, reason);
    if (state === ViroTrackingStateConstants.TRACKING_NORMAL) {
      setText("Hello World!");
    } else if (state === ViroTrackingStateConstants.TRACKING_UNAVAILABLE) {
      // Handle loss of tracking
    }
  }

  return (
    <ViroARScene onTrackingUpdated={onInitialized}>
      <ViroText
        text={text}
        scale={[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]}
        position={[0, 0, -1]}
        style={styles.helloWorldTextStyle}
      />
    </ViroARScene>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <ViroARSceneNavigator
      autofocus={true}
      initialScene={{
        scene: HelloWorldSceneAR,
      }}
      style={styles.f1}
    />
  );
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  f1: { flex: 1 },
  helloWorldTextStyle: {
    fontFamily: "Arial",
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "#ffffff",
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});

`
This is how it looks in android phone
in android device running 14
When I run in MQ3
in meta quest 3
We used starter kit from viro which also ends up loading screen.
EDIT 1
on running AR the onInitialised return state 1 reason 1
state 1 means AR Camera position is not available.
reason 1 means The current tracking state is not limited.
EDIT 2
tried this reactviro_oculus
https://github.com/viromedia/viroreact-oculus/tree/master
but there isn't any documentation or support
